# EntityFramework not creating tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using EF for a while now, always in the [Model-First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362) approach. Now I'm adventuring through [Code-First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) lands.
The thing is: I've been having issues with automatic table creation.

According to some sites it is possible. And I've tried their approach with no success.

Here's one of the things I've tried: `Database.CreateIfNotExists()`

No luck...

My connection string is perfect and working. If I add the table manually it does work. The problem is when I don't have the table created. It just doesn't create as I was said it would.

My classes are correctly decorated. (Again: It's working when I have the DBs created)

Any suggestions? Does this feature really works?

I'm using:

> Visual Studio 2010 Professional
>
> EntityFramework 4.3.1 (although I tried with 4.1 also)
>
> SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create your own context class that derives from DbContext? and then make a call which would use DbSet<YourEntity> Entities within the context

Comment: Database.CreateIfNotExists() will only cause EF to create the table if the database itself does not exist (in which case it creates the database and table).  It will not cause it to automatically create the table if a database exists but the table happens to be missing.  Is this maybe what you're running into?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, I did that.

Comment: @JohnW True, the DB already existed when I tried that approach. Is there any way to work with an existing DB? The only things I want to create/drop/update are the tables. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there's a built in `System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>` that will do this.  Most seem to drop the entire database before doing anything.  If you want things to be done automagically, but advice would be to use a `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer.

Comment: @JohnW Ok, that's for EF 5.0b, but I might give it a try. The thing is that even when I didn't have the DB created I couldn't create it. My Connection String is correct, but it was trying to access the DB 'master' and not the one I set in the Connection String. I might give it a better look as it seems I'm doing something very wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three database initializers that are included with entity framework they all implement `IDatabaseInitializer<Context>` interface. They are:

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExist (default)
- DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways

As you see the default API does not have the initializer that just creates tables, instead it does the whole database. However there are other initializers that people have created, there is one that does exact same thing that you want.

It's in the Nuget package `EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly`

Another option is to create your own initializer if that's something you really need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Later tonight I'll try that and let you know how it went by accepting the answer. Thanks again!